# Robotium : How to target elements by ID in robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

I want to enter text in a text field, so if I will use index then my code goes:

```
solo.enterText(0, "text");
```

But **I want to use id instead of index**. I have the source code but I have not added it to test project,using APK to test. I can get ids from source code.

How can I use id instead of index?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
 solo.enterText((EditText)solo.getView(int/String id), String text);
```

Comment: Where I can get the id as I have not added the source code of AUT in my project and if I will mention the id (e.g login_field) in place of id then this throws an error like string not declared as R.java of the AUT is not present in my test project.

Comment: just put it as String

Answer (score 0):

to get the id for a view if you dont have access to the source code use Hierarchy View tool
start an emulator, install the application, open the view and then go to Hierarchy View to get the id's

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#indiView

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answer your own question, the easiest way is to include the Application you are testing as a dependancy of your test app then you can use its R files in your test app and it will work as you expect. If however this is not an option you should use robotium's new functionality (4.2+) to get the ID by a string such as:

```
solo.getView("com.xxx.yyy.R.id.zzz");
```

where com.xxx.yyy is the package name of the app you are testing and zzz is the id of the element you want to click. If you do not know zzz then use the hierarchy viewer to find it.

Comment: could this work with getEditText as well ?